My Iwata ALG 7WB TE spray gun is leaking from the nozzle gland. Should there be some kind of seal / thread tape etc?
Today I cleaned my Iwata ALG 7WB TE (might be an older model than the one marketed at present). There was a lot of gunk around the thread on the nozzle gland set (3) where it meets the gun body (5). I removed the paint residues, and the gun started leaking at that place.

When I unscrew the nozzle gland set there's just a thread, and no seal or gasket by the threads or in the seat in the gun body -- so what's supposed to make it tight? Actually I can't understand why it didn't leak to begin with, but maybe the paint residue formed a seal before I washed it away ...
In the sparse manual on the Iwata website there's no mention about any seal or the like.
